# Why do we have unbiased estimator if the data are missing at random

Tags: probability-theory, linear-regression

Suppose we are trying to model by linear regression $$ on $$. However, we only observe $(,)$ for $=1$. Assume that the true model is:
$$Y = X'\beta + e$$
with $E(e|X) = 0$.

We know that $(|,)=(|)$, meaning that the missingness has nothing to do with the outcome. Why can we ignore the missing data in this case? Why will we have unbiased estimators?

I have seen many resources on econometrics claiming this without giving a proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you can write
$$
R_iY_i=R_iX_i^{\top}\beta+R_i\varepsilon_i, \quad i=1,\ldots, n.
$$
The LS estimator of $\beta$ is then given by
$$
\hat{\beta}=\beta+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n R_iX_iX_i^{\top}\right)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n R_iX_i\varepsilon_i.
$$
If $\mathsf{E}[\varepsilon_i\mid R_i,X_i]=0$, the estimator is unbiased. This holds if, for example, $R_i$ is conditionally independent of $\varepsilon_i$ given $X_i$ (MAR assumption) and $\mathsf{E}[\varepsilon_i\mid X_i]=0$ (standard OLS assumption).

Comment: why does $(|,)=(|)$ imply $ [∣,]=0$?

Comment: @Rainroad https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence

Comment: Would it still hold if $E(eX) = 0$ instead of mean independence condidtion?

Comment: @Rainroad Then you cannot show unbiasedness. But the estimator is still consistent.